# Is there a way to only specifically port forward to a virtual machine and not to the host at all?

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to run a Minecraft server on a Linux virtual machine, but not allow any access at all to the Windows machine it is running on. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use **Bridged Network** instead of NAT/NAT Network/Host Only.  This will put the VM on the same subnet as the host machine's adapter you've bridged to, giving it its own IP on your LAN, etc.  Then set your router to forward to its IP and not your Windows host machine's IP.